# Jasper Studio : Convert 24 format time to 12 format

Tags: jasper-reports

How can i convert 24 format time to 12 format in jasper studio via expressions?
i have string like below
`"19:00"` and i want to convert it to `"07:00 PM"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same as in java see [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as you can see the correct format is `hh:mm a`

The best solution in jasper-reports is using `pattern` attribute on the `textField` tag since it will conserve the time object if you export to for example excel

```
<textField pattern="hh:mm a">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"uuid="b8baea82-84c4-42fa-bccd-62abc96eeded"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{theTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Another solution is using the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in `textFieldExpression`

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format($F{theTime})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

NOTE: `$F{theTime}` needs to be of the class `java.util.Date` or one of its extensions `java.sql.TimeStamp`,`java.sql.Date`,`java.sql.Time`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pattern property..

1. Click on the Text Field you want to format.
2. Right click, click Show Properties.
3. Click on the Text Field tab.
4. Look for Pattern and click on the square with the 3 dots (...).
5. Choose the type of pattern you want to format your Text Field to. You can type a new format yourself if you are not satisfied with the pre-defined ones.

Same as above can be achieved by going to Advanced Properties and looking for the Pattern property.

Hope it helped. Cheers :)